# Any relevance to the title "The Young Unicorns"?

Tags: soft-sci-fi

The Young Unicorns, is a part of a set of stories about the Austin Family. I just recently read the book and there is absolutely no reference to unicorns at all in the book. There is a lot of science fiction about mind control, but I don't see why anyone would title the book so. Is there some obscure reference to unicorns I am missing?

Comment: Even on Wikipedia, I couldn't find a reference to a unicorn at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Madeleine L'Engle's 1968 novel, The Young Unicorns, takes its title from an apocryphal writing of St. Macrina: "In their early days they were like the unicorn, wild and uncommitted, which creature cannot be caught by the hunter, no matter how skillful. Nay, but he can only be tamed of his own free will."

From what I can tell, this quote appears in the book ([not my image](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/the-young-unicorns)):
[image]

From [one source](http://shreddedcheddar.blogspot.com/2010/03/jmj-madeleine-lengle-novel-smackdown.html), the following analysis is offered:

> The title of this novel comes from the writings of St. Macrina (the Younger?), who describes the unicorn as a creature which can be tamed only of its own free will. Indeed, the main theme of the story is whether freedom is possible in structure--in what, to other people, is practically slavery. Can one be free even when most tightly and narrowly bound?

The same source reveals also who the unicorns are:

> The two "young unicorns" are Emily Gregory, a talented young pianist blinded in a mysterious accident, and Josiah "Dave" Davidson, a former hood who mistrusts open doors and yet has a collection of keys to every door in the city's huge Episcopalian cathedral. They are lucky to have a couple of "old unicorns"--the Dean of the cathedral and Emily's piano teacher--taking an interest in them.

Another [source](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m1252/is_18_134/ai_n25341043/) focusing on the author's life also links St. Macrina to The Young Unicorns and offers it's own explanation.

Comment: Great links! When I googled around, I found only Wikipedia.